# Oracle SQL regexp_substr number extraction behavior

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In a sense I've answered my own question, but I'm trying to understand the answer better:

When using regexp_substr (in oracle) to extract the first occurrence of a number (either single or multi digits), how/why do the modifiers `*` and `+` impact the results?  Why does `+` provide the behavior I'm looking for and `*` does not?  `*` is my default usage in most regular expressions so I was surprised it didn't suit my need.

For example, in the following:

```
select test, 
regexp_substr(TEST,'\d') Pattern1,
regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*') Pattern2, 
regexp_substr(TEST,'\d+') Pattern3
from (
select '123 W' TEST from dual
union
select 'W 123' TEST from dual
);
```

the use of `regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*')` returns null value for the input "W 123" - since 'zero or more' digits exist in the string, I'm confused by this behavior.  I'm also confused why it does work on the string '123 W'

my understanding is that `*` means zero or more occurrences of the element it follows and `+` means 1 or more occurrence of the preceding element.  In the example provided for pattern2 `[\d*]` why does it successfully capture "123" from "123 W" but it does not take 123 from "W 123" as zero or more occurrences of a digit do exist, they just don't exist in the beginning of the string.  Is there additional [implied] logic attached to using `*`?

Note: I looked around for a while trying to find similar questions that helped me capture the '123' from 'W 123' but the closest i found was variations of regexp_replace which would not meet my needs.

Comment: This is a really good question, because I agree with you that it seems `\d*` would match `123` in the string `W 123`. I have ran into similar issues though with regex when using `*`. This might provide some insight for you: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/why-using-the-greedy-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the regexp_count indicates there are FOUR substrings that match the \d* pattern.
The third of those is the '123'. The implication is that the first and second are derived from the W and space and what you have is a zero length result that 'consumes' one character of the source string.

```
select test, 
    regexp_count(TEST,'\d*') Pattern2_c, 
    regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*') Pattern2,
    regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*',1,1) Pattern2_1,
    regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*',1,2) Pattern2_2,
    regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*',1,3) Pattern2_3,
    regexp_substr(TEST,'\d*',1,4) Pattern2_4
 from (select '123 W' TEST from dual
    union
    select 'W 123' TEST from dual
    );
```

Oracle has a weird thing about zero length strings and null.

The result doesn't "feel" right, but then if you ask a computer deep philosophical questions about how many zero length substrings are contained in a string, I wouldn't bet on any answer.

Comment: Oracle assuming a zero length string is `NULL` drives me crazy. I've encountered numerous issues related to this.

Comment: "how many zero length substrings"? The answer is `length(str) + 1` in all cases and all regexp flavors, have you ever seen any other result?

Answer (score 2):

After thinking through this, it actually makes sense. The pattern `\d*` is saying to match any number **zero** or more times. The problem here is that the beginning of the string will always match this pattern, because of the zero or more times.

If the string begins with a number, then it will include those numbers, so given `123 W`, the pattern matches `123`. However, given the pattern `W 123` the pattern also matches at the beginning, but it matches against 0 characters. This is why you get a `NULL` result.

This is a general regex thing and not an Oracle thing. You have to be careful with the `*` quantifier.

Here are two regex fiddle examples to illustrate this, using the string `W 123`:

- [`\d+` shows 1 match on `123`](https://regex101.com/r/r6myi0/1)
- [`\d*` shows 1 match on nothing (i.e. the beginning of the string)](https://regex101.com/r/qGT79N/1)

Comment: That is right - with the additional clarification (also general to all regular expressions, not just Oracle) that a match is attempted from the beginning of the string **first**. If no match is found, then a match is attempted starting after the first character; if no match is found there either, then ... (repeat). In the case of `\d*` a match is **always** found starting at the beginning of the string (sometimes of length zero, sometimes longer), so no other match is needed or attempted starting at other positions. Simple as that!

Comment: @mathguy Yes, thanks for clarifying. This is what I was trying to say but you said it much better!

Comment: The important idea - I struggled with regular expressions till I understood this clearly - is that a string has "characters" but also has "positions" (between characters, and before the first and after the last character). Regular expressions extend from such a "position" to another "position" (or to the same position for matches of length zero). Anchors like ^ and $, but also - not supported by Oracle! - things like word boundaries, lookahead and lookaround etc. are all about "positions" in the string, not "characters".